# How can I extend Color Palette in Material UI with Typescript

Tags: typescript, material-ui, next.js

I am new on react and typescript.
I am trying to extend the color palette on a global theme.

in my themeConitainer.tsx

```
import { ThemeOptions } from '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme';

declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette' {
  // allow configuration using `createMuiTheme`
  interface Palette {
    accent: PaletteColor
  }
  interface PaletteOptions {
    accent: PaletteColorOptions,
    tertiary: PaletteColorOptions
  }
};

const ThemeContainer: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props, themeOptions: ThemeOptions) => {
  const { children } = props;

  const theme = useMemo(() => {
    const nextTheme = createMuiTheme({
      ...themeOptions,
      palette: {
        accent: {
          main: '#ff0000'
        },
      }
    });

    return nextTheme;
  });

  return <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>;
};

export default ThemeContainer;
```

but on my component, there was an error.

[image]

No overload on this call.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8):

not 100% sure in TS, but it works for me like this:

```
declare module "@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette" {
  interface Palette {    
    lightWarning: Palette["primary"];
  }
  

  interface PaletteOptions {    
    lightWarning: PaletteOptions["primary"];
  } 

}
```

Find a brief introduction at the projekt homepage:
https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#customization-of-theme

Or in this article:
https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/extend-material-ui-theme-in-typescript-a462e207131f

Answer (score 7):

For those arriving here using MUI 5, you can overwrite the `Palette` and `PaletteOptions` with your custom types, then just extend those interfaces with the existing types:

```
declare module '@mui/material/styles/createPalette' {
  interface Palette {
    neutralShade: {main: string};
  }

  interface PaletteOptions {
    neutralShade?: {main: string};
  }
}
```

Comment: This works when using `theme.palette.neutralShade` directly but I am still seeing the TS error when using that color with a component. E.g., `<Chip color="neutralShade" />`.

Comment: If you want to use the color in the color property of the component, you should override the interface for color's components, named as `ComponentNamePropsColorOverrides`. You can follow the last piece of code that is showed in [MUI documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/#adding-new-colors)

Answer (score 1):

for mui v5, its:-

```
import * as createPalette from '@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette';

declare module '@mui/material/styles/createPalette' {
  interface NeutralPaletteColoOptions {
    main?: string;
  }
  interface NeutralColorPalette {
    main: string;
  }
  interface PaletteOptions {
    success?: PaletteColorOptions;
    warning?: PaletteColorOptions;
    neutral?: NeutralPaletteColoOptions;
  }
  interface Palette {
    success: PaletteColor;
    warning: PaletteColor;
    neutral: NeutralColorPalette;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

> The short answer is that you can't (and you shouldn't) do this.

The long answer contains the following explanation:

[Material UI](https://material-ui.com/) is (one of) React's implementations of the Material Design concept.

[Material Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_Design) is a design language that Google developed in 2014. Expanding on the "card" motifs that debuted in Google Now, Material Design uses more grid-based layouts, responsive animations and transitions, padding, and depth effects such as lighting and shadows.

As part of Material Design you have the [color system](https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#color-usage-palettes), which contains a primary/secondary (and a variant for each of them).
You also have the dark/light theme which you can control, and each of them also have primary/secondary colors.

If you need more colors - you probably don't follow the idea of Material Design.

You can always use CSS/Variables/Styled components for extra design options, but in general you shouldn't.

Comment: I upvoted this because it's a valid argument. However, AFAIK, Material Design is just a guideline, not a complete and strict design system. I saw a lot of professional designers altering it to their own liking. So, the question is also valid.

Comment: Not quite true. In Material Design you have specific number of colors, and each of them has a specific meaning and purpose. You can't really just add new colors. If you do so - you are not keeping the original idea/structure of the Material Design system.
However I do appreciate the upvote :-) thanks @MaximMazurok!

Comment: As a developer, I agree with you. But designers in my experience tend to have their own opinion on the matter, they treat material guidelines not as strict rules. And they sometimes use "everything is a mix" creative approach by mixing material cards with custom elements and colors. So, if OP's job is to develop a website with altered material design - then his case is valid. Even though it's not "pure" material design, sometimes a dev's got to do what a dev's got to do ;D

Comment: not sure about upvoting or downvoting (so I won't).
You're correct that you can usually just switch the primary or secondary colors, but then MUI actually have documentation about extending the theme so it clearly isn't frowned upon. https://mui.com/customization/theming/ . There are certain cases where users might need many themes if the user can customize their UI for example or a developer needs to switch between styles quickly to show alternatives to a client.