# How do I extend the color palette from mui with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to extend the color palette that mui provides. The overriding of primary, secondary etc colors works well but if I want to create a custom set of colors just after, I can't figure out how to make it works. There are plenty of examples without typescript but when this guy comes into the game it makes it trickier. Let's say I have this:

theme.tsx

```
palette: {
  primary: {...}, // override works
  custom: { 
    main: 'color', 
    dark: 'color1', 
    light: 'color2', 
    contrastText: 'color3' 
  }
}
```

from what mui document says, I should use module augmentation:

```
declare module "@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette" {
  interface Palette {
    custom: Palette['primary'];
  }
  interface PaletteOptions {
    custom: PaletteOptions['primary'];
  }
}
```

Nothing is yelling, but when I use it for a Box component for example, it doesn't work (others like primary.dark works well). It's been several days that I'm trying to find out how to do this, but I have to say I'm out of knowledge there.

I'd appreciate some help! Thanks! :)

Ps: Someone already posted the same question but it didn't help me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61097813/how-can-i-extend-color-palette-in-material-ui-with-typescript)

Answer (score 8):

As others mentioned, the documentation shows how to add a color to the theme interface, but not for the color property of components. I think I found a proper solution in the source code. This example is using Material UI 5, so I'm not sure if it works in 4, and I couldn't find any official docs on it.

In my example, the Chip component exports [several interfaces](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/Chip/Chip.d.ts#L12) which you can extend with declaration merging. The following code should allow you to set the color of a chip to "facebook" or "twitter"

```
// define custom colors: https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/
declare module '@mui/material/styles/createPalette' {
  interface Palette {
    facebook: Palette['primary'];
    twitter: Palette['primary'];
  }
  interface PaletteOptions {
    facebook: PaletteOptions['primary'];
    twitter: PaletteOptions['primary'];
  }
}

// Extend color prop on components
declare module '@mui/material/Chip' {
  export interface ChipPropsColorOverrides {
    facebook: true
    twitter: true
  }
}
```

Comment: This helped me get to the right place, but for anyone else who lands here: 1) the `ChipPropsColorOverrides` custom properties shouldn't be quoted 2) `Chip` requires a `contrastText` property be defined on your custom palette color, otherwise you'll get an `undefined` error when it tries to parse that color

Comment: Thanks @ChiefMcFrank I don't have the quotes in my code either so I removed them from my example.

Comment: it is not a relevant answer, since your answer works for MUI v5, but the question was related to MUI v4. And they have a pretty big differences in this place in particular

Answer (score 7):

### MUI 5

This is the approach I took for extending the palette in MUI 5.

You can remove the `extends` however you still need to import the `Palette` and `PaletteOptions` without the aliases. This might cause some issues with the linter, though (unused imports).

To avoid any gross `eslint disable` stuff, I just overwrote the types and extended them with the existing types by importing them under an alias.

```
import {
  Palette as MuiPallete,
  PaletteOptions as MuiPaletteOptions,
} from '@mui/material/styles/createPalette';

declare module '@mui/material/styles/createPalette' {
  interface Palette extends MuiPallete {
    neutralShade: {main: string};
  }

  interface PaletteOptions extends MuiPaletteOptions {
    neutralShade?: {main: string};
  }
}
```

No idea if there is a better way but this seemed the cleanest to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can extend it like this

```
import { Color, Palette, PaletteOptions } from '@mui/material';

export interface MyGrey extends Color {
  custom: string;
}

export const myGrey: MyGrey = {
  custom:'#FFFFFF'
}

interface MyPaletteExtensions {
  myGrey: MyGrey;
}

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface Palette extends MyPaletteExtensions {}
  interface PaletteOptions extends MyPaletteExtensions {}
}

export const myPalette: PaletteOptions = {
  primary: {
    light: '#FFFFFF',
    main: '#FFFFFF',
    dark: '#FFFFFF',
  },
  secondary: {
    light: '#FFFFFF',
    main: '#FFFFFF',
  },
  myGrey,
};
```

This will then allow

```
theme.palette.myGrey.custom
```

One thing to bear in mind with the above approach you can't extend the default palette keys e.g `grey` it must be a custom name had we done `theme.palette.grey.custom` this would work but give a TS error.

Answer (score 1):

This is from my current project. I reuse the primary type.

```
declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette' {
    interface Palette {
        magic: Palette['primary'];
    }
    interface PaletteOptions {
        magic: PaletteOptions['primary'];
    }
}

export const Theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        magic: { main: '#1a1a1a' },
    }
})
```

Comment: Yes, I had it like you. But that doesn't work on my side. 
When I write  bgcolor='custom.main' into my Box, it doesn't take into account the color and I also doesn't have any hint of what goes wrong as nothing is red. 
So for you this is working fine?

Comment: you will need to [customize your components](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/) or do something like `style={{backgroundColor: theme.pallette.magic.main}}`

Comment: Thanks! Might be a stupid question but how to you import your ```theme.pallette.magic-main```, this doesn't recognize it automatically, right ?

Comment: There are different options. Easiest is to use the `useTheme` hook from material-ui or to [customize your components](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/) . I would recommend reading about [theming in material-ui](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/)

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the source code, you should be using:

```
declare module "@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette" {
  interface Palette {
    custom: PaletteColorOptions;
  }
  interface PaletteOptions {
    custom: PaletteColorOptions;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why this is documented like that though.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. 
When adding PaletteColorOption, my custom colors turn red and it says 'Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'custom' does not exist in type 'PaletteOptions' ' .