# Material UI React Typescript - Extending Theme Colors - can't fix typescript Problems

Tags: reactjs, typescript, colors, material-ui, themes

New to typescript here, and very confused, can anyone help?
So I'm using material-ui with typescript in my React project. If someone wants to add a new color the, you know, "right" way, they have to add it to a theme:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: blue[400]
    },
    secondary: {
      main: green[500]
    },
    neutral: {
      main: "#abcdef" // <-- NEW COLOR
    }
  }
})
```

Then you use it in your ThemeProvider wrapper component whenever you want to use a theme. Straight from the docs. However, if the victim is also trying to use typescript, they have to extend the Palette interface (again the docs give this as an example) ..

```
declare module "@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette" {
  interface Palette {
    neutral: Palette["primary"]
  }
  interface PaletteOptions {
    neutral: PaletteOptions["primary"]
  }
}
```

Again, just copied/pasted from the docs. Seems to make sense! Now typescript doesn't complain about the new property in the palette anymore. Now, it's time to try out my new color! However, when I try to use it in a component:

```
<IconButton color="neutral" onClick={onClose}> {/* big problem!! */}
   <CloseIcon />
</IconButton>
```

Here's where I get confused. Typescript complains! I mean it's typescript's job to complain, I suppose, but I can't figure out how to deal with it. There is a red squiggle on 'color' because the type of the color prop doesn't have "netural" as an option.

[Image of the red squiggly line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjsAl.png)

But of course, I an new, and I might be missing something obvious.
So, like I said, the component's props are defined as a 'type' not an interface or anything like that, and the 'color' is another type within it which only accepts certain stings, I just have to get it to recognize "neutral", and I can't figure it out. Is there a way? (without using ts-ignore)

```
{/* 
// @ts-ignore */}
<IconButton color="neutral" ...
```

(would prefer not to do this)

I feel like there should be an easy fix if I'm gonna use colors the "right" way .. and I'm just not seeing it. Please help!!

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that you cannot pass arbitrary values for `color` prop to `IconButton` as well as to any other material-ui's `Button`s. Only redefine existing theme colors: `primary` and `secondary`. This behavior is [hardcoded](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/a194311/packages/material-ui/src/IconButton/IconButton.js#L49-L74)(4.x) and not going to change in the foreseeable [future](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/6209295/packages/material-ui/src/IconButton/IconButton.js#L73-L98)(5.x).

Only [className/classes](https://material-ui.com/api/icon-button/#css) overrides as proposed by Barryman9000.

---

As for types I believe there is no easy way to override `PropTypes.Color` type definition for 4.x. But since 5.x(@next) you can [extend or restrict](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/36a9ed9/packages/material-ui/src/IconButton/IconButton.d.ts#L28-L31) `IconButton`'s `color` prop acceptable values by merging `IconButtonPropsColorOverrides` interface:

```typescript
interface IconButtonPropsColorOverrides {
  neutral: true // allow `neutral` to be used as a color prop value
  primary: false // forbid using `primary`
}
```

Though you still have to implement actual behavior logic for those values. They won't work right away (as of current (2021-05) state of @next code)

Comment: In my case (with MUI v5) the `IconButtonPropsColorOverrides` approach works as expected. I did not have to implement anything else fortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this. I think the issue is that you're just extending the theme object but the `<IconButton />` component's `color` prop is of type `PropTypes.Color` where `Color` is a union type and only accepts these four values

```
export namespace PropTypes {
  type Color = 'inherit' | 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'default';
}
```

I've used a couple different approaches to get around this. With the `useTheme()` hook you can access your `neutral` theme color from the palette in your component or you can create a styled component and access your palette from there

In your component

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const { palette } = useTheme();

  return (
    <IconButton
      color={palette.neutral.main}
    >...</IconButton>)
}
```

styled-component

```
const MyStyledComponent = styled(IconButton)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: theme.palette.neutral.main
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, although for me using <IconButton color={palette.neutral.main} > still produces a typescript issue. Hmm. And I'm currently not using styled components in my project
I guess I'll just use a slightly hacky workaround for now

Comment: That's odd, there shouldn't be a TS error... what is the error?

Comment: If you want to try `styled-components` you can just use the Material-ui styled API: https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#styled-component-styles-options-component

Comment: Hi idk if this is still useful but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64932595/how-do-i-extend-the-color-palette-from-mui-with-typescript

This link and user helped to figure things out pretty well