# MUI Override Slider color options with module augmentation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to solve a typescript error regarding the chosen color on my slider component:

```
<Slider
  color="brown"
/>
```

The error is: `Type '"brown"' is not assignable to type '"primary" | "secondary" | undefined'.`

I have set the brown color on my theme, by augmenting the createPalette file.

```
declare module '@mui/material/styles/createPalette' {
    interface Palette {
        brown: PaletteColor
    }

    interface PaletteOptions {
        brown: PaletteColorOptions
    }
}
```

So now that I still have the error I looked in the `Slider.d.ts` file and found an interface: `SliderPropsColorOverrides`.

```
export interface SliderPropsColorOverrides {}
...
color?: OverridableStringUnion<'primary' | 'secondary', SliderPropsColorOverrides>;
```

I try to merge it with my brown color:

```
declare module '@mui/material/Slider' {
    interface SliderPropsColorOverrides {
        darkest_blue: PaletteColorOptions
    }
}
```

But with no luck. Either my IDE (PhpStorm 2021.3) isn't compiling the new typescript code, or I'm missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were very close to something that would work, but the value for the augmentation of `SliderPropsColorOverrides` should just be `true` rather than `PaletteColorOptions`.

In my [example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/slider-custom-color-tr6x4) I have the following key pieces:

**createPalette.d.ts**

```
import "@mui/material/styles/createPalette";
declare module "@mui/material/styles/createPalette" {
  interface Palette {
    brown: PaletteColor;
  }
  interface PaletteOptions {
    brown: PaletteColorOptions;
  }
}
```

**Slider.d.ts**

```
import "@mui/material/Slider";

declare module "@mui/material/Slider" {
  interface SliderPropsColorOverrides {
    brown: true;
  }
}
```

There was one other problem that I addressed in a rather ugly fashion. The `Slider` prop-types were still causing a runtime validation message for the `color` prop. I found comments in some open issues about color customization that mention this prop-types aspect and I suspect it will eventually be addressed by MUI, but it might not be addressed for a while. In my sandbox, I work around this by creating a [SliderPropTypesOverride.ts](https://codesandbox.io/s/slider-custom-color-tr6x4?file=/SliderPropTypesOverride.ts) file in which I copied [MUI's SliderRoot.propTypes.ownerState](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v5.2.6/packages/mui-material/src/Slider/Slider.js#L363) and then modified the `color` portion to include "brown". This copying of the prop-types definitely isn't ideal from a maintenance standpoint, but at the moment I don't see another way to address the runtime warning in dev mode.

Then this all gets used as follows:

**demo.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import "./SliderPropTypesOverride";
import Slider from "@mui/material/Slider";

const defaultTheme = createTheme();
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    brown: defaultTheme.palette.augmentColor({
      color: {
        main: "#A52A2A"
      },
      name: "brown"
    })
  }
});

export default function Demo() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Slider color="brown" />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Slider custom color]

Related answers:

- [Typescript Module augmentation is not working: Property 'main' does not exist on type 'PaletteColorOptions'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68844584/typescript-module-augmentation-is-not-working-property-main-does-not-exist-on/68854872#68854872)
- [How to add custom colors name on Material UI with TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68430166/how-to-add-custom-colors-name-on-material-ui-with-typescript/68433584#68433584)

Answer (score -1):

I would review the documentation on this.

[https://mui.com/customization/palette/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61097813/how-can-i-extend-color-palette-in-material-ui-with-typescript)

It doesn't seem that you're able to override the color of the component directly and instead (if you have one) need to create a global theme object with the appropriate declaration files in order to override the color.

Also see this answer:
[Extending the color palette with TS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61097813/how-can-i-extend-color-palette-in-material-ui-with-typescript)